# Change Button Text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am learning php and want to set the display text for a button that I have.  I know that you can use javascript to change the button text,but that (at least from what I have seen) works for .onclick  I want the button text to be changed when the page loads.  By default the button text on my page when it loads displays `Submit Query` when my page loads I want the text to read `Button on Page` 
Is there a way using php to 
1) set the button text and 
2) have it span 2 rows in the table?

This is the code I am working with:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="TestForm" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="calculationfields">
            <table id="calculations">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="lblreadonly1:">Read Only 1:</label></td>
                <td><input  type="text" name="txtReadOnly1" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="lblreadonly2:">Read Only 2:</label></td>
                <td><input  type="text" name="txtReadOnly2" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="lblreadonly3:">Read Only 3:</label></td>
                <td><input  type="text" name="txtreadonly3" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>             
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn123" text="Button On Page"></td>  
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: under what condition should the button text be different?

Comment: Page Load - I want the default text of the button to be Button On Page

Comment: So why not just changing the html then?

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use value instead of text for your submit button

```html
<body>
        <form id="TestForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="calculationfields">
                <table id="calculations">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lblreadonly1:">Read Only 1:</label></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" name="txtReadOnly1" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lblreadonly2:">Read Only 2:</label></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" name="txtReadOnly2" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lblreadonly3:">Read Only 3:</label></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" name="txtreadonly3" maxlength="50" size="10" readonly></td>             
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn123" value="<?php echo 'Button On Page'; ?>" style="width:100%"></td>  
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: That changes text - how can the button span both columns?

Comment: @WooBinWooYeol, I changed the code. you can put your variable inside the php code block

Answer (score 0):

If you always know what you want your button to say, you don't need php or javascript. You can just use the html "value" attribute. You are incorrectly using a attribute labled "text", you should use "value". Update your code to the following.

Change your button html from:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn123" text="Button On Page">
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn123" value="Button On Page">
```

Edit:

In order to have your button go full width. You should use "colspan" instead of "rowspan". Your td is in a row, and needs to span columns.

Change this code from:

```
<td rowspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn123" value="Button On Page"></td>
```

to (note that I added an id of "button" to your button):

```
<td rowspan="2"><input type="submit" id="button" name="btn123" value="Button On Page"></td>
```

Then add a little css:

```
#button{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle with a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/joeydehnert/m1ttcr86/

Comment: Thank you, that changes text.  What to do to center the button across both columns?